# Add redundacy disk to Synology Hybrid Raid

Tags: raid-1, synology

I have a DS216j NAS by Synology that currently hosts a single 4 TB disk.

Volume is set to SHR (Synology Hybrid Raid) *(without data protection)*.

Now I bought another disk, same model, same size.

I want to add it as a redundacy disk, i.e. add data protection to my SHR configuration.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Synology documentation you can add a disk to add redudnancy.

[Here it documents the process](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID_SHR)

The process is as below:

1. Install an additional hard drive in your Synology NAS.
2. Go to Storage Manager > Volume > Manage > Expand the volume by adding hard disks.
3. When the new drive is added to the SHR volume, the volume will have 1-disk fault tolerance.

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is that this will lead to a simil-RAID0 configuration (not mirrored) because when clicking on "Manage" the unique active option "Add drives to SHR volume" says "For a SHR volume containing one drive, storage capacity will only be expanded when two or more drives are added".

Comment: @Teejay to me that makes sense. If you add 1 drive, to a 1 drive setup, it won't increase storage, because it's going to RAID1... ?

Comment: Yeah, but not so clear IMHO. Anyway, it worked, thanks!

Comment: @Teejay just ran into this myself but I think it is actually clear. SHR with 1 drive, you get size=x, no redundancy. Adding *two or more* will increase capacity... but we are increasing by <2, so capacity will not be increased. Thus, we can deduce that the 1 added drive's "capacity" is for redundancy.